# cucumber.js And is not a function

Tags: javascript, cucumber, bdd, assert

I am practicing in writing some unit test by BDD use cucmber.js.
When I try to use 'And' statement. The error shows that

```
TypeError: And is not a function
```

Here is my code

.feature

```
Feature: dataTable
Scenario Outline: <a> + <b> + <c> = <answer>
  Given I had number <a>
    And I add another number <b>
  When I add with <c>   
  Then I got answer <answer>

Examples:
|a|b|c|answer|
|1|2|3|6|
|10|15|25|50|
```

.stepDefinition

```
defineSupportCode(function({Given,When,Then,And}){
  let ans = 0;
  Given('I had number {int}', function(input){
    ans = input
  })
  And('I add another number {int}',function(input){
    ans += input
  })
  When('I add with {int}',function(input){
    ans += input
  })
  Then('I got answer {int}', function(input){
    assert.equal(ans,input)
  })
})
```

and the error message is like below:

```
TypeError: Add is not a function
    at ...  // my file location
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test_cucumber@1.0.0 cucumber: `cucumber.js ./test/e2e/Features -r ./test/e2e/StepDefinition`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test_cucumber@1.0.0 cucumber script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/lab1321_mac_air/.npm/_logs/2018-01-04T08_15_28_568Z-debug.log
```

I wonder if I wrote something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: when you enter the callback of `definedSupportCode`, what is the `console.log(typeof And)`?

Comment: the error you show is `Add is not a function` ... in the title it's `And is not a function` ... please clarify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`And` and `But` are syntactical sugar for the feature file - in other words, they are aliases for `Given`, `When` and `Then`.

When you are defining the step, you should use `Given`, `When` and `Then` to describe what the step is trying to achieve (a prerequisite, an action or an outcome), and then if you have more than one prerequisite, action or outcome, use `And` or `But` in your feature file only.