# Getting scenario and steps undefined in cucumber with Node Js

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, playwright, cucumberjs

Here I create a Cucumber Js project in eclipse.
My Folder Structure is

[image]

My Feature file code

```
@tag
Feature: Title of your feature
 

  @tag1
  Scenario: Title of your scenario
    Given I want to write a step with precondition
    And some other precondition
```

And Step Definition Code

```
import {Given,And} from '@cucumber/cucumber'


Given('/^I want to write a step with precondition$/', async function () {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           return 'pending';
         });
         
 And('/^some other precondition$/', async function () {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           return 'pending';
         });
```

And Cucumber.js code

```
let common=[
    'features/login.feature',
    '--format-options {"snippetInterface":"async-await"}',
    '--publish-quiet'
].join(' ');


module.exports={
    default:common
}
```

When I try to run it throwing error as 'undefined'
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cucumber.js And is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020181/cucumber-js-and-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

@cucumber/cucumber does not implement `And` keyword of `Gherkin` grammar.

If `And` attached to `Given` group, you may use `Given` keyword like provided snippet. Do same for `And`s in `When` and `Then` groups.

Instead of repeating `Given`, usage of `And` or `But` keywords makes scenarios more readable.

You should see "Cannot resolve symbol 'And'" error for `And` import.

```js
import {Given,And} from '@cucumber/cucumber'
              ^^^ Cannot resolve symbol 'And'
```

Maybe, you would like to import Given as And to feel more comfortable in your coding.

```js
import {Given, When, Then, Given as And} from '@cucumber/cucumber'
```